# Variables arent updating accordingly

Tags: java

When I attempt to take in the users input and update the "Dexterity" variable, it only reflects in the following few lines of code. When I attempt to run the same command again, it doesn't reflect the previous input. For some reason It is not updating the variable accordingly.

```
public class SetAttributes {

    public String userInput;
    double Dexterity;
    double Strength;
    double Intelligence;
    double Stamina;
    double SkillPoints = 50;



    public SetAttributes() {
        this.SetDex(0);
        this.SetStr(0);
        this.SetInt(0);
        this.SetSta(0);
        this.SetSkillPoints(50);
    }

    public double GetSP(){
        return SkillPoints;

    }
    public double GetDex() {
        return Dexterity;
    }
    public void SetDex(double dexterity) {
        this.Dexterity = dexterity;
    }

    public double GetStr(){
        return Strength;
    }

    public double GetInt(){
        return Intelligence;
    }

    public double GetSta(){
        return Stamina;
    }





    public void SetStr(double strength){
        this.Strength = strength;
    }
    public void SetInt(double intelligence){
        this.Intelligence = intelligence;
    }
    public void SetSta(double stamina){
        this.Stamina = stamina;
    }
    public void SetSkillPoints(double skillPoints) {this.SkillPoints = skillPoints;};
}
```

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public final class PointSpender {


    public static void Spend() {

        SetAttributes A = new SetAttributes();

        System.out.println("Your current stats are ");
        System.out.println("Strength " + A.Strength);
        System.out.println("Stamina " + A.Stamina);
        System.out.println("Intelligence " + A.Intelligence);
        System.out.println("Dexterity " + A.Dexterity);

        System.out.println("Please select the attribute you want to increase. You have " + A.SkillPoints + " available.");

        Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);

        A.userInput = Input.nextLine().toLowerCase();

        if(A.userInput.charAt(0) == 'd'){
            System.out.println("Dexterity");
            System.out.println("Your Dexterity is " + A.Dexterity);
            System.out.println("How many points in Dexterity?");



            double Amount = Double.parseDouble(Input.nextLine());

            A.SetDex(A.GetDex() + Amount);
         //   A.setDex(A.Dexterity + Amount);


            System.out.println("You have put " + Amount + " into Dexterity" );
            System.out.println("Your new dexterity is " + A.Dexterity);





        }
    }
}
```

> ```
>                           Type "+" to spend your available skillpoints.
>                                 Type "Logout" to Log Out.
> +
> Your current stats are 
> Strength 0.0
> Stamina 0.0
> Intelligence 0.0
> Dexterity 0.0
> Please select the attribute you want to increase. You have 50.0 available.
> d
> Dexterity
> Your Dexterity is 0.0
> How many points in Dexterity?
> 45
> You have put 45.0 into Dexterity
> Your new dexterity is 45.0
> +
> Your current stats are 
> Strength 0.0
> Stamina 0.0
> Intelligence 0.0
> Dexterity 0.0
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Every time you invoke the static method "spend" you are creating a new instance of SetAttributes  then you are blocking for user input. But before the block when the new instance is created all attributes of the new instance are set to 0.

This happens in your zero argument constructor, right here :

```
public SetAttributes() {
        this.SetDex(0);
        this.SetStr(0);
        this.SetInt(0);
        this.SetSta(0);
        this.SetSkillPoints(50);
    }
```